# How to render React Component depending on result of If condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-component

Is there any easy way how can I render React component into App.js but based on result from if condition? I have clock app which is supposed to 'ring' when alarm value which I define is equal to current time. This 'ring' effect I want to be that another component ,for example Ring.js will render when current time is equal to alarm time and it will contain text from state a I can simply unmount it by clicking a button.

**Here Is my function with condition which is called every second to check if there's value in alarmHours state or not.**

```
  function checkTime(){
   if(time.alarmHours && time.alarmMinutes){
    if(time.currentHour === time.alarmHours && time.currentMinute === time.alarmMinutes && 
     time.currentSecond === '00'){
      //VALUES ARE EQUAL ,ALARM IS RINGING,RENDER COMPONENT
     }
    }
   }
```

My first idea was to create empty variable ,and if the condition is fulfilled just simply insert Ring.js component into that variable.

```
let ring;

function checkTime(){
  if(time.alarmHours && time.alarmMinutes){
    if(time.currentHour === time.alarmHours && time.currentMinute === time.alarmMinutes && 
    time.currentSecond === '00'){
      ring = <Ring />
    }
  }
}
```

And then, simply render that variable in Return() of App.js ,like this.

```
Return(
  <div>
    {ring}
  </div>
)
```

But it doesn't work a nothing is rendered.

I've tried to look in official React documentation ,they have there few examples but I don't really get how to implement that approach in my case. I don't know how to render that component if that condition is fulfilled. Can anybody please help me? I'll appreciate that. Thank you.

Link for codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-paper-xv0wi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You should add a state variable: `const [ringing, setRinging] = useState(false);`. Further down in your JSX, you use `{ringing && <Ring />}`. Finally, when the alarm time is reached, you call `setRinging(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would update your `checkTime()` function to return `<Ring />` if it's ready, otherwise return null and then you can just:

```
return (
  <div>
    {checkTime()}
  </div>
);
```

i.e.

```
function checkTime(){
  if(time.alarmHours && time.alarmMinutes){
    if(time.currentHour === time.alarmHours && time.currentMinute === time.alarmMinutes && 
    time.currentSecond === '00'){
      return <Ring />
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

`ring` is no longer needed.

EDIT: additional question in comments

if you want `Ring` to show when the alarm time has been reached, I would change the pattern and introduce a new boolean state value like `const [showRing, setShowRing] = React.useState(false)` which is initially set to false. `checkTime()` would then no longer return any JSX and just also call `setShowRing(true)` and then you would:

```
return (
  <div>
    {showRing && <Ring />}
  </div>
);
```

i.e.

```
function checkTime(){
  if(time.alarmHours && time.alarmMinutes){
    if(time.currentHour === time.alarmHours && time.currentMinute === time.alarmMinutes && 
    time.currentSecond === '00'){
      setShowRing(true);
    }
  }
}
```

And wherever you want to remove the `<Ring />` you would call `setShowRing(false)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works for now,but after second <Ring /> component dissapears. I need it to stay on screen until i press the button to unmount it. Do you have any solution for that? @Anthony

Comment: @Pinnci I added an edit to cover this additional scenario

Comment: thank you sooo much. Is it possible to separate all this new code in that Rinkg.js file? Like I did it Alarm.js and then I'm just calling it. I mean I would like to add some kind of animation to it ,so to keep code nice and readable it would be nice

Comment: I'm trying like for an hour to keep all of the <Ring /> separated from App.js and  animate that Ring component and I swear to god it is impossible. I've just tried everything possible.

Comment: @Pinnci I would try asking a new question to keep it focussed

Comment: Im on it.. hope 90minutes limit is gone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63288360/how-to-display-and-animate-react-component-depending-to-result-of-condition-with here it is

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let ring = <Ring />;

function checkTime(){
  if(time.alarmHours && time.alarmMinutes){
    if(time.currentHour === time.alarmHours && time.currentMinute === time.alarmMinutes && 
    time.currentSecond === '00'){
      return true;
    }
  }
   return false;
}
...

return (
  <div>
   {checktime() ? ring : null}
  </div>
)
```